# SSMS, changing future values after a certain value is recorded

Tags: ms-access, duplicates

**UPDATE** Can anyone help me with my previous question below, but instead of coding this in to MS Access, I need to write this in SQL Server Management System (SSMS)? Thanks!!!

I have a simple question that has been more difficult that I had imagined. What I'm trying to do is create a query based off a table that is updated daily. Within my query are test results. What I want to be able to do is once a patient is tested "Positive", every test performed after that be changed to "Retest" regardless if it positive or negative. I also only want this to kick in on the first positive, so if they have negatives before, they stay negative, but anything after that first positive should be "Retest" Here is an example:

```
Patient  Date     Test

Patient1 1/1/2020 Negative
Patient1 2/5/2020 Negative
Patient1 2/8/2020 Positive
Patient1 3/9/2020 Retest
Patient1 4/5/2020 Retest
```

Now this is mixed in with other patients, so it would be like this:

Headers

```
Patient  Date      Test

Patient1 1/1/2020  Negative
Patient2 1/5/2020  Negative
Patient3 2/1/2020  Negative
Patient4 2/2/2020  Positive
Patient1 2/5/2020  Negative
Patient1 2/8/2020  Positive
Patient1 3/9/2020  Retest
Patient2 3/10/2020 Negative
Patient4 3/11/2020 Retest
Patient1 4/5/2020  Retest
```

With this patient 1 and 4 eventually were positive and all tests after that are changed to "Retest". I was hoping this could get done with one formula for this query, but now I'm thinking I'll have to create a table that has patient information with 1st positive test and another table with those same patients with all other test results, change the results in this table and join it back in to a primary table... let me know your thoughts!

Update, this is the part of my MS Access code that is slowing down my query. There is more to this query, but this step is what is slowing it down.

```
Status: Max(Nz((Select Top 1 "RETEST" 
    From [tblIMMCLocations] As P 
    Where P.[Patient Name] = [tblIMMCLocations].[Patient Name] And P.[Order Date] < [tblIMMCLocations].[Order Date] And P.[Result] = "DETECTED"),[tblIMMCLocations].[Result]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will do that:

```sql
SELECT 
    Patients.Patient, 
    Patients.Date, 
    Nz(
        (Select Top 1 "Retest" 
        From Patients As P 
        Where P.Patient = Patients.Patient And P.Date < Patients.Date And P.Test = "Positive"),
        [Test]) AS Status
FROM 
    Patients
ORDER BY 
    Patients.Date,
    Patients.Patient;
```

Comment: Thank you Gustav, this looks like it should work, I'll try it tomorrow and post if I have any issues. To clarify, this will keep the first positive result and every test after that will say "Retest"? I've never used Nz() and "select top 1".

Comment: Yes, it will return your sample as requested.

Comment: Thank you again Gustav! I was able to input my table and columns names in to this query and it appears to be working. I'll have to look in to the logistics of how this works so I can understand it better, but so far so good. You have saved me a ton of time.

Comment: Thanks again for the help with this, but I've come across a new issue with this. This query has been working great, but just today, this query went from running in a few minutes to running for 20+ min to finish. Nothing has changed. Raw data is up to 13k+ rows, but ran it yesterday just fine. Any ideas? We possibly had a site wide software update, could that have done something? So confused...

Comment: If you (temporarily) can roll back that update and the query will run fine, it's the update. If not, check indexes on the fields in the Where clause.

Comment: Update already happened, so I'm working to fix this now. I checked the Where clause, the tables it references are large but have no issues. Is there something else I should be looking for specifically? I guess I'm unfamiliar with what I should be looking for when checking the indexes

Comment: Go to table design and study the indexes. If no index on the fields, create these.

Comment: Thanks. So for this process, it creates about 10 tables all together, should I only index those that are involved with the query that is running slow? or just do all of them? Because of the purpose and specific requests for this report, I can only choose "Yes - Duplicates are Accepted", will this improve the performance better than choosing no?

Comment: Start with those running slow. A duplicate index is OK.

Comment: It seems to be running better from some of the changes I've made however, each time it runs it creates new tables, so the index settings get set back to "No". When tables are created, can you designate the index?

Comment: Change your code from _creating_ a new table to _appending_ to an existing table.

Comment: Follow up question: How do you write this same exact code for SQL SSMS? (instead of access)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have SSMS at hand but, I guess, it would be something with _IsNull_ instead of _Nz_.